# Theorem 6.15 in Baby Rudin: If $a<s<b$, $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous at $s$, and $\alpha(x)=I(x-s)$, then . . .

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Here is Theorem 6.15 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> If $a<s<b$, $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous at $s$, and $\alpha(x)=I(x-s)$, then 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d \alpha = f(s). $$

Here is Definition 6.14:

> The *unit step function* $I$ is defined by 
>   $$ I(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \qquad & (x \leq 0), \\ 1 \qquad & (x > 0). \end{cases} $$

And, here is Rudin's proof:

> Consider partitions $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3 \  \right\}$, where $x_0 = a$, and $ x_1 = s < x_2 < x_3 = b$. Then 
>   $$ U(P, f, \alpha) = M_2, \qquad L(P, f, \alpha) = m_2. $$ 
>   Since $f$ is continuous at $s$, we see that $M_2$ and $m_2$ converge to $f(s)$ as $x_2 \to s$.

Now here is my reading of Rudin's proof:

First of all, here are Definitions 6.1 and 6.2 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

Definition 6.1:

> Let $[a, b]$ be a given interval. By a *partition* $P$ of $[a, b]$ we mean a finite set of points $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, where 
>   $$ a = x_0 \leq x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_{n-1} \leq x_n = b.$$
>   We write 
>   $$ \Delta x_i = x_i - x_{i-1} \qquad (i = 1, \ldots, n). $$ 
>   Now suppose $f$ is a bounded real function defined on $[a, b]$. Corresponding to each partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ we put
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  M_i &= \sup f(x) \qquad (x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i), \\
> m_i &= \inf f(x) \qquad (x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i), \\
> U(P, f) &= \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta x_i, \\
> L(P, f) &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta x_i,
> \end{align}
>  $$
>   and finally 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \tag{1} \overline{\int}_a^b f dx &= \inf U(P, f), \\
> \tag{2} \underline{\int}_a^b f dx &= \sup L(P, f),
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where the $\inf$ and the $\sup$ are taken over all partitions $P$ of $[a, b]$. The left members of (1) and (2) are called the *upper* and *lower* *Riemann integrals* of $f$ over $[a, b]$, respectively.
>
> If the upper and lower integrals are equal, we say that $f$ is *Riemann-integrable* on $[a, b]$, we write $f \in \mathscr{R}$ (that is, $\mathscr{R}$ denotes the set of Riemann-integrable functions), and we denote the common value of (1) and (2) by 
>   $$ \tag{3} \int_a^b f dx, $$
>   or by 
>   $$ \tag{4} \int_a^b f(x) dx. $$
>   This is the Riemann integral of $f$ over $[a, b]$. Since $f$ is bounded, there exist two numbers, $m$ and $M$, such that 
>   $$ m \leq f(x) \leq M \qquad (a \leq x \leq b). $$
>   Hence, for every $P$, 
>   $$ m(b-a) \leq L(P, f) \leq U(P, f) \leq M (b-a), $$
>   so that the numbers $L(P, f)$ and $U(P, f)$ form a bounded set. This shows that *the upper and lower integrals are defined for every bounded function $f$.* . . .

Definition 6.2:

> Let $\alpha$ be a monotonically increasing function on $[a, b]$ (since $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b)$ are finite, it follows that $\alpha$ is bounded on $[a, b]$). Corresponding to each partition $P$ of $[a, b]$, we write 
>   $$ \Delta \alpha_i = \alpha \left( x_i \right) -  \alpha \left( x_{i-1} \right). $$
>   It is clear that $\Delta \alpha_i \geq 0$. For any real function $f$ which is bounded on $[a, b]$ we put 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> U(P, f, \alpha) &= \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta \alpha_i, \\
> L(P, f, \alpha) &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta \alpha_i, 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where $M_i$, $m_i$ have the same meaning as in Definition 6.1, and we define 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \tag{5} \overline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha = \inf U(P, f, \alpha), \\
> \tag{6} \underline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha = \sup L(P, f, \alpha), 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   the $\inf$ and $\sup$ again being taken over all partitions. If the left members of (5) and (6) are equal, we denote their common value by 
>   $$ \tag{7} \int_a^b f d \alpha $$
>   or sometimes by 
>   $$ \tag{8} \int_a^b f(x) d \alpha(x). $$
>   This is the *Riemann-Stieltjes integral* (or simply the *Stieltjes integral*) of $f$ with respect to $\alpha$, over $[a, b]$.
>
> If (7) exists, i.e., if (5) and (6) are equal, we say that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\alpha$, in the Riemann sense, and write $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.

Now for the proof of Theorem 6.15:

> For any partition $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, x_2 , x_3  \ \right\}$ of the closed interval $[a, b]$, where 
>   $$a = x_0  < x_1 = s < x_2 < x_3 = b,$$ 
>   we note that 
>   $$
> \begin{align} 
>  U(P, f, \alpha) 
> &= M_1 \left[ \alpha \left( x_1 \right) - \alpha \left( x_0 \right) \right] + M_2 \left[ \alpha \left( x_2 \right) - \alpha \left( x_1 \right) \right] + M_3 \left[ \alpha \left( x_3 \right) - \alpha \left( x_2 \right) \right] \\
> &= M_1 ( 0 - 0) + M_2 ( 1 - 0) + M_3 ( 1 - 1 )  \\
> &= M_2, 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   and similarly, $L(P, f, \alpha) = m_2$; thus 
>   $$ U(P, f, \alpha) = M_2, \qquad L(P, f, \alpha) = m_2, \tag{A} $$
>   and so $$U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) = M_2 - m_2, \tag{B} $$
>
> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. As $f$ is continuous at the point $s \in (a, b)$, so  we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that $$ a < s-\delta < s < s + \delta < b,$$
>   and 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(s) \rvert < { \varepsilon \over 4 } $$
>   for all $x$ which satisfy $\lvert x-s \rvert < \delta$.
>
> Thus, if $s < x_2 < s+\delta$, then we must have 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(s) \rvert <  { \varepsilon \over 4 } $$
>   for all $x \in \left[ s, x_2 \right] =  \left[ x_1 , x_2 \right]$. 
>   That is, 
>   $$ f(s) - { \varepsilon \over 4 } < f(x) < f(s) + { \varepsilon \over 4 }$$
>   for all $x \in \left[ x_1, x_2 \right]$. Therefore, we must have 
>   $$ f(s) - { \varepsilon \over 4 } \leq m_2 \leq M_2 \leq f(s) + { \varepsilon \over 4 }, \tag{C} $$ 
>   and so, by (B) above, 
>   $$  U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) = M_2 - m_2 \leq   { \varepsilon \over 2 } < \varepsilon,$$
>   from which it follows (by Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition) that $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$.
>
> Now as 
>   $$ m_2 =  L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \int_a^b f d \alpha \leq U(P, f, \alpha) = M_2, \qquad \mbox{ [ using (A) ]
>  } $$ 
>   so (C) implies that 
>   $$ f(s) - { \varepsilon \over 4 } \leq m_2  \leq \int_a^b f d \alpha  \leq M_2 \leq f(s) + { \varepsilon \over 4 },  $$ 
>    and so 
>   $$ f(s) - { \varepsilon \over 4 }  \leq \int_a^b f d \alpha   \leq f(s) + { \varepsilon \over 4 },  $$ 
>   which in turn implies that 
>   $$ \left\lvert \int_a^b f d \alpha - f(s) \right\rvert \leq  { \varepsilon \over 4 } < \varepsilon$$
>   for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, showing that 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d \alpha = f(s), $$
>   as required.

Is my rendering of Rudin's proof correct and to the point? If not, then at which point have I gone astray?

Comment: Actually, if $|f(x)-f(s)|<\frac{\epsilon}{4},$ then $M_i-m_i\leq \frac{\epsilon} {4}$

Comment: Write $I$ be that subinterval. Pick any $s \in I$. For all $x\in I$, we have $f(x)\leq f(s)+\epsilon$. Therefore, $f(s)+\epsilon$ is an upper bound. And we have $M_i \leq f(s)+\epsilon$. So you might continue to do that get rid of those ugly coefficients in your proof next time.

Comment: @LiChunMin thanks for your comments. Can you please also comment on whether my proof has any issues?