# Theorem 6.17 in Baby Rudin, 3rd ed: $\int_a^b f \,d\alpha = \int_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) \,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Here is Theorem 6.17 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Assume $\alpha$ increases monotonically and $\alpha^\prime \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$. Let $f$ be a bounded real function on $[a, b]$.

> Then $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ if and only if $f\alpha^\prime \in \mathscr{R}$. In that case
> $$ \int_a^b f \,d\alpha = \int_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x)\, dx. $$

For terminology, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329858/theorem-6-15-in-baby-rudin-if-asb-f-is-bounded-on-a-b-f-is-contin) is the link to my post here on Math SE on Theorem 6.15 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition.

Here is Rudin's proof of Theorem 6.17:

> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and apply Theorem 6.6 to $\alpha^\prime$: There is a partition $P = \left\{ \ x_0, \ldots, x_n \  \right\}$ of $[a, b]$ such that
> $$ \tag{28} U(P, \alpha^\prime) - L(P, \alpha^\prime) < \varepsilon. $$
> The mean value theorem furnishes points $t_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$ such that
> $$ \Delta \alpha_i = \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \Delta x_i $$
> for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. If $s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, then
> $$ \tag{29}  \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) - \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \right\rvert \Delta x_i < \varepsilon, $$
> by (28) and Theorem 6.7 (b). Put $M = \sup \lvert f(x) \rvert$. Since
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i = \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \Delta x_i $$
> it follows from (29) that
> $$ \tag{30}  \left\lvert  \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i  -  \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i \right\rvert \leq M \varepsilon. $$
> In particular,
> $$  \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i  \leq U( P, f \alpha^\prime ) + M \varepsilon, $$
> for all choices of $s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, so that
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) \leq U(P, f \alpha^\prime) + M \varepsilon. $$
> The same argument leads from (30) to
> $$ U(P, f \alpha^\prime) \leq U(P, f, \alpha) + M \varepsilon. $$
> Thus
> $$ \tag{31} \left\lvert U(P, f, \alpha) - U(P, f \alpha^\prime ) \right\rvert \leq M \varepsilon. $$

> Now note that (28) remains true if $P$ is replaced by any refinement. Hence (31) also remains true. We conclude that
> $$ \left\lvert \overline{\int}_a^b f \, d \alpha - \overline{\int}_a^b f (x) \alpha^\prime(x) \,dx  \right\rvert \leq M \varepsilon. $$
> But $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary. Hence
> $$ \tag{32} \overline{\int}_a^b f \,d \alpha = \overline{\int}_a^b f (x) \alpha^\prime(x) \,dx  $$
> for *any* bounded $f$. The equality of the lower integrals follows from (30) in exactly the same way. The theorem follows.

Here is Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

> $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that
> $$ \tag{13} U(P, f, \alpha ) - L(P, f, \alpha ) < \varepsilon. $$

Here is Theorem 6.7:

Theorem 6. 7(a):

> If (13) holda for some $P$ and some $\varepsilon$, then (13) holds (with the same $\varepsilon$) for every refinement of $P$.

Theorem 6. 7(b):

> If (13) holds for $P = \left\{ \ x_0, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ and if $s_i$, $t_i$ are arbitrary points in $\left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, then
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert f \left( s_i \right) - f \left( t_i \right) \right\rvert \Delta \alpha_i < \varepsilon. $$

Theorem 6.7(c):

> If $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and the hypotheses of (b) hold, then
> $$ \left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( t_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i - \int_a^b f\, d \alpha \right\rvert < \varepsilon. $$

Now here is my understanding of Rudin's proof of Theorem 6.17:

> As $f$ is a bounded real function on $[a, b]$, so there is a positive real number $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $$ \lvert f(x) \rvert < M \tag{0} $$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be a given real number. As $\alpha^\prime$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$, so there exists a partition $P = \left\{ \ x_0, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ of $[a, b]$ such that
> $$ U(P, \alpha^\prime) - L(P, \alpha^\prime) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}. \tag{1} $$

> Now as  $\alpha^\prime$ exists on $[a, b]$, so,  For each $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, the function $\alpha$ is continuous on $\left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$ and differentiable on $\left( x_{i-1}, x_i \right)$, and hence  there exists a point $t_i \in \left( x_{i-1}, x_i \right)$ such that
> $$  \alpha \left( x_i \right) - \alpha \left( x_{i-1} \right) = \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \left( x_i - x_{i-1} \right); $$
> that is,
> $$ \Delta \alpha_i = \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \Delta x_i \tag{2} $$
> for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

> And, for each $i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}$, if $s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, then, as $t_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$ also, so we conclude that
> $$\tag{3a} m_i ( \alpha^\prime )  \leq \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \leq M_i (\alpha^\prime), $$
> and
> $$\tag{3b}  m_i (\alpha^\prime) \leq \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \leq M_i ( \alpha^\prime) ,  $$
> where
> $$ m_i ( \alpha^\prime ) \colon=  \inf \left\{ \ \alpha^\prime (x) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i \ \right\}, $$
> and
> $$ M_i ( \alpha^\prime) \colon= \sup  \left\{ \ \alpha^\prime (x) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i \ \right\};$$
> now (3b) implies that
> $$ \tag{3c} - M_i ( \alpha^\prime ) \leq - \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \leq - m_i (\alpha^\prime),  $$
> and upon adding (3c) to (3a), we obtain
> $$ m_i ( \alpha^\prime ) - M_i( \alpha^\prime) \leq \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) - \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \leq M_i ( \alpha^\prime) - m_i( \alpha^\prime),   $$
> which implies that
> $$ \left\lvert \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) - \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \right\rvert \leq M_i ( \alpha^\prime) - m_i( \alpha^\prime),  \tag{3d} $$
> and, as $\Delta x_i = x_i - x_{i-1} \geq 0$, so (3d) yields
> $$ \left\lvert \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) - \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \right\rvert \Delta x_i \leq \left[ M_i ( \alpha^\prime) - m_i( \alpha^\prime) \right] \Delta x_i,  \tag{3e} $$
> for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

> Now upon adding together all the inequalities in (3e), we get
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n  \left\lvert \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) - \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \right\rvert \Delta x_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ M_i ( \alpha^\prime) - m_i( \alpha^\prime) \right] \Delta x_i,  $$
> that is,
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n  \left\lvert \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) - \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \right\rvert \Delta x_i \leq U(P, \alpha^\prime) - L(P, \alpha^\prime). \tag{3} $$

> From (1) and (3) we get
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n  \left\lvert \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) - \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \right\rvert \Delta x_i < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}, \tag{4} $$
> for any points $s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, for each $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$; the points $t_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$ are as given in (2) above.

> Now from (2) we see that
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i = \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \Delta x_i, \tag{5a} $$
> where the points $s_i$ and $t_i$, for each $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, are as in (4) above.

> So
> \begin{align} 
> & \ \ \ \left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i - \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i  \right\rvert \\ 
> &= \left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right) \Delta x_i - \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i  \right\rvert \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ by (5a) ] } \\
> &= \left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \left[ \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right)  - \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \right] \Delta x_i  \right\rvert \\
> &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert  f \left( s_i \right) \left[ \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right)  - \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \right] \Delta x_i  \right\rvert \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert  f \left( s_i \right)  \right\rvert  \left\lvert  \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right)  - \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right)  \right\rvert \Delta x_i   \\
> &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n M \left\lvert  \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right)  - \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right)  \right\rvert \Delta x_i   \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using (0) above ] } \\
> &= M \sum_{i=1}^n  \left\lvert  \alpha^\prime \left( t_i \right)  - \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right)  \right\rvert \Delta x_i   \\
> &< M \frac{\varepsilon}{2M} \qquad \mbox{ [ using (4) above ] } \\
> &= \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.   
> \end{align}

> Thus we have shown that
> $$ \left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i - \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i  \right\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{5} $$
> for any points $s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, for each $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

> From (5) we can conclude that, for any points $s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, for each $i \in \{  1, \ldots, n\}$, we have
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i - \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, $$
> and so
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i &<  \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i +  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
> &\leq U( P, f \alpha^\prime) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{6a} 
> \end{align}
> for any point $s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, for each $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$.

> Now we show that $$ U(P, f, \alpha) = \sup \left\{ \ \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i \colon \ s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right] \mbox{ for each } i = 1, \ldots, n \ \right\}. \tag{6b} $$

> For each $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, let
> $$M_i(f) \colon= \sup \left\{ \ f(x) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i \ \right\}; \tag{6c} $$
> now as $ f \left( s_i \right) \leq M_i (f)$ and as $\alpha$ is a monotonically increasing function on $[a, b]$ and hence also on $\left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, so
> $$ \Delta \alpha_i = \alpha \left( x_i \right) - \alpha \left( x_{i-1} \right) \geq 0,$$
> and therefore
> $ f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i \leq M_i(f) \Delta \alpha_i$ for each $i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}$, which implies that
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n M_i(f) \Delta \alpha_i = U(P, f, \alpha). $$
> Thus $U(P, f, \alpha)$ is an *upper bound* of the set in (6b).

> If $\alpha$ is constant on the interval $[a, b]$, then, for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we have $\Delta \alpha_i = 0$ and so all the sums in the set in (6b) are zero,
> and also  $U(P, f, \alpha) = 0$, and so  (6b) holds.

> So let's assume that $\alpha$ is not constant on the interval $[a, b]$. Then there exists a sub-interval
> $\left[ x_{k-1}, x_k \right]$ (for some $k = 1, \ldots, n$) such that
> $$\Delta \alpha_k = \alpha\left( x_k \right) - \alpha\left( x_{k-1} \right) > 0. \tag{*}$$

> As $\varepsilon > 0$ and as $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing on $[a, b]$, so, for each $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, we have
> $$ M_i(f) - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1  } < M_i(f),$$
> and thus the real number $ M_i(f) - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1 } $ is not an upper bound of the set in (6c), which implies that there exists a point $p_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$ such that
> $$ M_i(f) - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1  } < f\left(p_i\right),$$
> and since $\Delta \alpha_i \geq 0$, we have
> $$ \left[ M_i(f) - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1 } \right] \Delta \alpha_i \leq  f\left(p_i\right) \Delta \alpha_i$$
> for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$; but for $i= k$ we have
> $$ \left[ M_k(f) - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1 } \right] \Delta \alpha_k <  f\left(p_k\right) \Delta \alpha_k;$$
> therefore,
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ M_i(f) - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1 } \right] \Delta \alpha_i < \sum_{i=1}^n  f\left(p_i\right) \Delta \alpha_i,$$
> that is,
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n M_i(f) \Delta \alpha_i - \frac{\varepsilon }{\alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1 } \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right]   < \sum_{i=1}^n  f\left(p_i\right) \Delta \alpha_i,  $$
> which is the same as
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - \frac{\varepsilon }{\alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1 } \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] < \sum_{i=1}^n  f\left(p_i\right) \Delta \alpha_i.
> \tag{6d} $$

> But, as $a \leq b$ and as $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing, so
> $$ \alpha(a) \leq \alpha(b), $$
> which implies that
> $$ 0 \leq \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) < \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1, $$
> and so
> $$ 0 \leq \frac{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a)  }{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) + 1 } <  1, $$
> which then  implies that
> $$ 0 \leq \frac{ \varepsilon  }{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) +1 } \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] < \varepsilon, $$
> and hence
> $$ - \varepsilon < - \frac{ \varepsilon  }{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) +1 } \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right]  \leq 0, $$
> which implies that
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - \varepsilon < U(P, f, \alpha)  - \frac{ \varepsilon  }{ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) +1 } \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] , \tag{6e} $$

> Now from (6d) and (6e) we have
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) -  \varepsilon < \sum_{i=1}^n  f\left(p_i\right) \Delta \alpha_i,  $$
> which shows that no real number less than $U(P, f, \alpha)$ can be an upper bound of the set in (6b).

> Thus the real number $U(P, f, \alpha)$ is an upper bound of the set in (6b), but no real number less than $U(P, f, \alpha)$ is an upper bound of that set. Therefore (6b) holds.

> Now from (6a) we see that the real number $U(P, f \alpha^\prime) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ is an upper bound for the set in (6b), and from (6b) we know that $U(P, f, \alpha)$ is the *least upper bound* of this very set, so from (6a) and  (6b) we can conclude that
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) \leq U(P, f \alpha^\prime) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{6} $$

> Again from (5) we obtain
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i -  \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i <  \frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$
> which implies that
> \begin{align} 
> \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i 
> &< \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i +  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
> &\leq U(P, f, \alpha) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{7a} 
> \end{align}
> for any point $s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

> We can show that
> $$ U(P, f\alpha^\prime) = \sup \left\{ \ \sum_{i=1}^n f \left( s_i \right) \alpha^\prime \left( s_i \right) \Delta x_i \ \colon \ s_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right] \mbox{ for each } i = 1, \ldots, n \ \right\}. \tag{7b} $$

> From (7a) and (7b) we can conclude that
> $$ U(P, f\alpha^\prime) \leq  U(P, f, \alpha) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{7} $$

> Now if $Q$ be any partition of $[a, b]$ such that $Q \supset P$, then (by Theorem 6.4 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition) we have
> $$ L(P, \alpha^\prime) \leq L(Q, \alpha^\prime) \leq U(Q, \alpha^\prime) \leq U(P, \alpha^\prime), $$
> which implies that
> $$ U(Q, \alpha^\prime) - L(Q, \alpha^\prime) \leq U(P, \alpha^\prime) - L(P, \alpha^\prime), $$
> and this together with (1) implies that (1) also holds for $Q$, and  therefore both (6) and (7) also hold for $Q$.

> That is, if $Q$ is any refinement of $P$, then
> $$ U(Q, f, \alpha) \leq U(Q, f \alpha^\prime) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{6*} $$
> and
> $$ U( Q, f\alpha^\prime) \leq  U(Q, f, \alpha) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{7*} $$

> Now let's suppose that
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f \,d \alpha -   \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) \,d x > \varepsilon. \tag{8a} $$

> As
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) \,dx + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} > 
> \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) \,dx, $$
> so there exists a partition $P_1$ of $[a, b]$ such that
> $$ U\left( P_1, f \alpha^\prime \right) <  \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{8b} $$
> which implies
> $$- U\left( P_1, f \alpha^\prime \right) > - \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - \frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$
> and so by (8a) we obtain
> \begin{align}
>  \overline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha - U \left( P_1, f \alpha^\prime \right) &> \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha -
>  \int_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
> &> \varepsilon - \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
> &= \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 
> \end{align}
> which implies that
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha - U \left( P_1, f \alpha^\prime \right) > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{8c} $$
> Now  if $Q$ is any partition of $[a, b]$ such that $Q \supset P_1$, then (by Theorem 6.4 in Baby Rudin)
> $$ U(Q, f\alpha^\prime) \leq U \left( P_1, f\alpha^\prime \right),$$
> and this together with  (8b) implies that
> $$ U(Q, f\alpha^\prime) <  \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{8b*} $$
> from which we obtain
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha - U(Q, f \alpha^\prime ) > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{8c*} $$
> in just the same way as we have obtained (8c) from (8b).

> Now let $Q$ be any partition of $[a, b]$ such that $Q \supset P$ and $Q \supset P_1$.
> Then (8c*) holds for this $Q$ as well.

> But as
> $$ U(Q, f, \alpha) \geq \overline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha, $$
> so (8c*) gives
> $$  U(Q, f, \alpha) - U \left( Q, f \alpha^\prime \right)  \geq \overline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha - U \left( Q, f \alpha^\prime \right)  
> > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, $$
> which implies
> $$  U(Q, f, \alpha) - U \left( Q, f \alpha^\prime \right)  > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, $$
> and so
> $$  U(Q, f, \alpha) >  U \left( Q, f \alpha^\prime \right)  + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, $$
> which contradicts (6*). Therefore (8a) cannot hold, and so
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha - \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx \leq \varepsilon. \tag{8} $$

> Now let's suppose that
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha > \varepsilon. \tag{9a}$$
> As
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} > \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha, $$
> so there exists a partition $P_2$ of $[a, b]$ such that
> $$ U \left( P_2, f, \alpha \right) <  \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{9b} $$
> which implies that
> $$ - U \left( P_2, f, \alpha \right) > - \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, $$
> which together with (9a) gives
> \begin{align}
> \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - U \left( P_2, f, \alpha \right) &> \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx -
> \int_a^b f d\alpha - \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
> &> \varepsilon - \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
> &= \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 
> \end{align}
> which implies that
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - U \left( P_2, f, \alpha \right) > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{9c} $$

> Now if $Q$ is any partition of $[a, b]$ such that $Q \supset P_2$, then (by Theorem 6.4 in Baby Rudin)
> $$ U(Q, f, \alpha) \leq U \left( P_2, f, \alpha \right), $$
> which together with (9b) yields
> $$  U(Q, f, \alpha) <  \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{9b*} $$
> and then we obtain
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - U ( Q, f, \alpha ) > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \tag{9c*} $$
> in just the same way as we have obtained (9c) from (9b).

> Now let $Q$ be any partition of $[a, b]$ such that $Q \supset P$ and $Q \supset P_2$. Then (9c*) holds for this $Q$.

> But as
> $$ U ( Q, f \alpha^\prime) \geq \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx, $$
> so (9c*) gives
> $$ U(Q, f \alpha^\prime ) - U(Q, f, \alpha) \geq \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime (x) dx - U(Q, f, \alpha) > \frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$
> which implies
> $$  U(Q, f \alpha^\prime ) - U(Q, f, \alpha) > \frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$
> and so
> $$  U(Q, f \alpha^\prime ) >  U(Q, f, \alpha) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$
> which contradicts (7*).

> Thus (9a) cannot hold, and so we can conclude that
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha \leq \varepsilon. \tag{9}$$

> Now from (8) and (9) we can conclude that
> $$\left\lvert  \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha \right\rvert 
> \leq \varepsilon $$
> for any real number $\varepsilon > 0$. Hence
> $$\left\lvert  \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx - \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha \right\rvert 
> = 0, $$
> which implies that
> $$ \overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha = \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx. \tag{A}  $$

> An analogous argument gives
> $$ \underline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha = \underline{\int}_a^b f(x)  \alpha^\prime (x) dx. \tag{B} $$

> Now suppose $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$. Then
> $$ \underline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha = \overline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha, $$
> and then (A) and (B) together imply
> $$ \underline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx = \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx, $$
> showing that $f\alpha^\prime \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$.

> Conversely, suppose $f \alpha^\prime \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$. Then
> $$ \underline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx  = \overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx, $$
> and then (A) and (B) together imply
> $$ \underline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha = \overline{\int}_a^b f d \alpha , $$
> showing that $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$.

> Finally, we assume that $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ --- which (as we have just shown) is equivalent to assuming that
> $f \alpha^\prime \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$ --- and then find from (A) and (B) that
> $$ \int_a^b f d\alpha = \int_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) dx, $$
> as required.

Is my rendering of Rudin's proof correct? If not, then where have I erred?

I admit that my presentation is very very, very lengthy, but it is to
demonstrate my reasoning clearly and fully enough.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you for taking the time going through my rather lengthy post. Have I managed to get the proof correctly elaborated? What is it that you've edited in my post?

Comment: So far just typesetting issues, such as changing $f d\alpha$ to $f\,d\alpha.$ Possibly I'll go through the math a bit later.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've just editted my post, fixing some more issues. Can you please have a careful look through my post now?

Comment: It looks fine. Well done. Math newbie appreciates your teaching.

Comment: After 9c*, similar argument, which starts after 9a, can be applied to the other upper integral to obtain a similar inequality as 9c*, which then can be added to 9c* to obtain a contradiction. Just need to careful in using common refinements.